# Custom 404 with Gorilla Mux and std http.FileServer

Tags: go

I have the following code and everything works fine.

```
var view404 = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("views/404.html"))

func NotFound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.WriteHeader(404)
  err := view404.Execute(w, nil)
  check(err)
}

func main() {
  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.StrictSlash(true)
  router.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(NotFound)
  router.Handle("/", IndexHandler).Methods("GET")
  router.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
  http.Handle("/", router)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

A request to a route like `/cannot/find` shows my custom 404 template. All static files inside my `/public/` directory are also properly served.

I have a problem handling non-existent static files and showing my custom `NotFound` handler for them. A request to `/public/cannot/find` calls the standard http.NotFoundHandler which replies with

> 404 page not found

How can I have the same custom NotFoundHandler for normal routes and static files?

---

**Update**

I ended up implementing my own `FileHandler` by wrapping `http.ServeFile` as @Dewy Broto suggested.

```
type FileHandler struct {
  Path string
}

func (f FileHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  prefix := "public"
  http.ServeFile(w, r, path.Join(prefix, f.Path))
}

// ...

router.Handle("/css/styles.css", FileHandler{"/css/styles.css"}).Methods("GET")
```

Now my `NotFound` handler catches all missing routes and even missing files.

Comment: Eek. Now you will need a handler for every file you want to serve. Images, javascript etc... I like his hook solution better, but even that is a lot of code for such a simple goal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The FileServer is generating the 404 response. The FileServer handles all requests passed to it by the mux including requests for missing files. There are a few ways to to serve static files with a custom 404 page:

- Write  your own file handler using [ServeContent](http://godoc.org/net/http#ServeContent). This handler can generate error responses in whatever way you want. It's not a lot of code if you don't generate index pages.
- Wrap the [FileServer](http://godoc.org/net/http#FileServer) handler with another handler that hooks the [ResponseWriter](http://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter) passed to the FileHandler. The hook writes a different body when [WriteHeader(404)](http://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter.WriteHeader) is called.
- Register each static resource with the mux so that not found errors are handled by the catchall in the mux. This approach requires a simple wrapper around [ServeFile](http://godoc.org/net/http#ServeFile).

Here's a sketch of the wrapper described in the second approach:

```
type hookedResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    ignore bool
}

func (hrw *hookedResponseWriter) WriteHeader(status int) {
    hrw.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(status)
    if status == 404 {
        hrw.ignore = true
        // Write custom error here to hrw.ResponseWriter
    }
}

func (hrw *hookedResponseWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    if hrw.ignore {
        return len(p), nil
    }
    return hrw.ResponseWriter.Write(p)
}

type NotFoundHook struct {
    h http.Handler
}

func (nfh NotFoundHook) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    nfh.h.ServeHTTP(&hookedResponseWriter{ResponseWriter: w}, r)
}
```

Use the hook by wrapping the FileServer:

```
 router.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(NotFoundHook{http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public")))})
```

One caveat of this simple hook is that it blocks an optimization in the server for copying from a file to a socket.

Comment: Approach 2 would be great.

Comment: Thank you! I chose approach 3 as it gives me maximum control of what is being served. I don't have that many static files that they might mess up my code. See my update above.

Comment: Wonderful approach - and this doesn't just apply to a project with `Gorilla`