# How can I override 404 in Golang

Tags: go

I'm still learning how to use Go for web development, but when I'm trying to create a simple website I'm facing the following difficulties:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "html/template"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {

   fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(""))

   http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
       tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
   })

   /**
   *    This route will return a 404 error
   */
   http.HandleFunc("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       fmt.Fprint(w, "Test page")
   })

   /**
   *    If I replace fs to nil, /test route will be work, but non-existent routes
   *    will be return index.html template (home router) instead 404 error. Why?
   */

   http.ListenAndServe(":80", fs)
}
```

There is a conflict between `http.FileServer` and `http.HandleFunc`.

For example, when I write: `http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)`, all routes (`http.HandleFunc`) will work, but if I try to do something like this:

`http.ListenAndServe(":80", http. FileServer(http.Dir("")))`

no route works (except `http.HandleFunc("/"))`. Why?

And how do I override the 404 error page? I was hoping that Go had a method like `http.HandleError` that accepts an interface with `http.ResponseWriter` and `http.Request`, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: ["The handler is typically nil, in which case the DefaultServeMux is used."](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ListenAndServe). If the handler isn't nil, then DefaultServeMux isn't used. "If I replace fs with nil non-existent routes return index.html instead of 404. Why?" Because / matches all requests. And because it matches all requests any custom 404 responses can be written in that handler too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I replace fs to nil, /test route will be work, but non-existent routes will be return index.html template (home router) instead 404 error. Why?

Checking the docs for [`http.ListenAndServe`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ListenAndServe):

> `func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error`
> The handler is typically nil, in which case the DefaultServeMux is used.

If `handler` is nil then the default handler will be used and [`http.HandleFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#HandleFunc):

> HandleFunc registers the handler function for the given pattern in the DefaultServeMux. The documentation for ServeMux explains how patterns are matched.

So in your code you register two routes with `DefaultServeMux`; calling `http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)` uses the default handler (to which you added routes) so `/test` works (further info below!). However when you run `http.ListenAndServe(":80", fs)` you are passing in a specific handler (`fs`) so all requests will be sent to that handler (which will attempt to serve the files from your local filesystem).

From this point on I'll assume `http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)` is being used (as it does not really make sense to add handlers and then not use them).

The above mentioned [`ServeMux`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux) so lets check that documentation:

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash). Longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones, so that if there are handlers registered for both "/images/" and "/images/thumbnails/", the latter handler will be called for paths beginning with "/images/thumbnails/" and the former will receive requests for any other paths in the "/images/" subtree.

So the Mux takes in the request and works out which handler should be called to deal with the request (note that only one handler will be called). The match is based on the length of the pattern (so, in your example `/test` is longer than `/` so takes preference). This means that requests for `/test` will trigger `fmt.Fprint(w, "Test page")` and everything else will call the handler that loads `index.html`. It's important to note that you have not added a handler that references `fs` so that is unused (and the code will not compile - [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/JjXoKZPU4eK)).

Hopefully this explains what is happening; in terms of achieving the result you want here are some questions that should help:

- [Handling custom 404 pages with http.FileServer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62747416/11810946)
- [Expected root files and custom 404 with Golang Mux Router and http.FileServer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52425318/11810946)
- [Custom 404 with Gorilla Mux and std http.FileServer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26141953/11810946)
- [Golang. What to use? http.ServeFile(..) or http.FileServer(..)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28793619/11810946)
- [How to have golang redirect to frontend routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64687181/11810946)